# Codeigniter. How insert string value with timestamp format in table int() column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i want send date like "12.03.2014" in database in int column
in controller date its input type text.

```
$val = $this->backend->form_rules();
    if ($val->run()) {
        $todb = $this->backend->form_todb();
        $id = $db->add_newsone($todb);
        redirect("backend/news/edit/$id");
    }
```

how i can change my $todb['date'] into timestamp format and send in int(11) column?

Answer (score 0):

If your date is stored in `$todb['date']` you can:

```
$date = new Datetime($todb['date']);
$todb['date'] = $date->getTimestamp();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You will have to put it after `$todb = $this->backend->form_todb();` and before `$id = $db->add_newsone($todb);` also what PHP version are you using?

Comment: in localhost server - 5.3

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use strtotime:

```
strtotime("12.03.2014");
```